# Is Pattern Matching as expressive as Case Expression in Haskell?

Tags: functional-programming, haskell

#### Nomenclature

The term *expressive* in the question shall bear the same meaning as in the following sentence:

> A Turing Machine is as *expressive* as Lambda Calculus.

#### Introduction

While learning Haskell, I had noticed that there are 2 ways to achieve the same effect, namely Pattern Matching and Case Expression. For example,

```
-- Pattern Matching
not True  = False
not False = True

-- Case Expression
not x = case x of True  -> False
                  False -> True
```

I am also fully aware that Pattern Matching is actually [a form of syntax sugar that will be compiled into Case Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458434/pattern-matching-using-cases-vs-functions).

Therefore, we can be very sure that every Pattern Matching expression can be converted to Case Expression.

### Question

So, this is my question: Is the following statement true?

> Every Case Expression can be re-written using Pattern Matching.

Regardless of the truthiness of the statement above, I would be glad if you could provide a formal proof to support your answer.

#### P/S

The motivation that drove me to seek answer for this question is because I'm currently designing my own language, which I wish to have as less feature as possible, but not too minimal like Lambda Calculus which only have 3 features.

Comment: Pattern matching at the function head is compiled, more or less, to case expressions in the function body. Further, your use of case expressions involves pattern matching; pattern matching vs case expressions is a bit of an apples-to-oranges comparison.

Comment: Note that Haskell-specific questions are off-topic here. However, pattern matching is a concept general enough that this question can be made on-topic, removing the Haskell-specific parts.

Comment: You definitely *don't* want the meaning of "expressive" that makes Turing machines and the untyped lambda calculus equally "expressive". Haskell without pattern matching or Haskell without case statements are both Turing-complete and so would be equally as "expressive" by that meaning. Haskell without *either* is Turing-complete. It is very rare that you want to compare programming languages based on what functions they can compute. See [On the expressive power of programming languages](https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-6423(91)90036-W) by Matthias Felleisen for an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

The expression

```
case e of
  p1 -> e1
  p2 -> e2
  ...
```

can be rewritten as

```
let k p1 = e1
    k p2 = e2
    ...
 in k e
```

where `k` is a fresh identifier.

This translation assumes that the language has some way to define a local function by pattern matching (e.g. `let`).

---

If local functions can not be defined, there's always the possibility of lifting the definition to the top level. Indeed, any local definition

```
let f x1 ... xk = e in e'
```

having free variables `v1 .. vn` can be rewritten written as

```
(\f -> e') (globalF v1 ... vn)
```

provided that we also define a global function

```
globalF v1 ... vn x1 ... xk = e
```

Note that `globalF` has no free variables, by construction. I believe it is sometimes called a "supercombinator".

This naturally extends to the case where `x1 ... xk` are patterns, and we have multiple defining equations for `f` / `globalF`.

---

For example,

```
case x of True  -> False
          False -> True
```

cab be rewritten as

```
let f True  = False
    f False = True
 in f x
```

Comment: Apologies I don’t really understand how this answers my question ? Do you mind to be more concise ? For example provide your stance upon the statement I thrown out?

Comment: @WongJiaHau See the last edit for an example.

Comment: Thanks, but does that mean any other Case Expression can be rewritten eith pattern matching ? For example, how would you write the definition of fmap using only Pattern Matching?

Comment: @WongJiaHau Above I showed how to translate any case into a `let` expression. You should be able to apply it to any case expression.